# What is difference among performance testing on Mobile, Desktop and Web applications?

Tags: performance, mobile, web, desktop-application

I need to know the difference in performance testing on web, mobile and desktop applications like what would be the use cases and test scenarios on these three different platforms?

Comment: Welcome to SQA Saba, I suggest you edit your answer to ask one question someone can answer that hasn't already been answered on this site before.  Currently you are asking two questions and at least one of them is pretty open ended.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is generic, here is a generic answer:

**Web**:

- Client side browser performance measurements should be established to understand the load on the client side (each browser is a separate client and needs to be treated as such)
- Web Server and database/other back end parts should be measured to assure proper server performance
- Network performance can be extrapolated from the total performance time minus the server performance and client performance (total - serv - client = network)

**Desktop**:

- Database/Interface response times to distinguish dependency performance measurements
- Gui render times to determine the user performance impact (you can subtract the dependency performance to get what is strictly app rendering vs. communications
- Again if you have a network issue you can subtract the dependency and render times from the network time.  In general the desktop app should bypass network issues, otherwise why not use a web app instead.

**Mobile**:

- Web Server and database/other back end parts should be measured to assure proper server performance (this is often the same as web)
- Rendering of the Client device is needed to determine client side performance (each device is different and checked as such)
- Network performance can be extrapolated from the total performance time minus the server performance and client device performance (total - serv - client device = network)

P.S. Some of these take alot of different approaches/tooling/specifics so if you need more specific information please ask such after researching and specifying your exact needs.

P.P.S. Test cases and use cases depend on your app not the method, so you would actually have to provide specifics and re-ask that question.